# What does the grand sum of a linear transformation matrix tell us about its action on a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations, positive-semidefinite

Let:

- $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ be an $m \times m$ symmetric positive semi-definite matrix.
- $\mathbf{X}$ be a real $n \times m$ matrix whose columns are orthonormal.
- The grand sum of $\mathbf{X}$ be $k$. I.e., $\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j} = k$.
- $\mathbf{\Phi} = \mathbf{X} \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{X}^\top$.

What does $k$ tell us about the action of $\mathbf{X}$? I.e., if we know $k$ and some property or properties of $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ (value, trace, determinant, eigenvalues, etc.), what can we say about $\mathbf{\Phi}$? In particular, are there values of $k$ that have special meaning (e.g., $k = 1$)?

Comment: Notably, the orthonormality of the columns of $X$ means that $\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j}^2 = m$. With that, we see that the maximum possible value for the “grand sum” is $k=m$, and we will have $k=m$ if and only if all entries of $X$ are zero or one (which means that $X$ is a submatrix of the size $n$ identity matrix).

Comment: We similarly have a lot of information about $X$ if $k=-m$. I don’t believe that there is much to be said for the case where $|k|<m$

Comment: Thanks, that’s useful.